# How to avoid line break with `inline-block` elements

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

With the following code,

**CSS**

```
.inline{display: inline-block;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
</div>
```

I intend to avoid line break at `&nbsp;` (between an `"X"` and the following `div` item with `"Foo"`) (but allow line break between a `div` item with `"Foo"` and the following `"X"`).

As [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/) shows, line break can actually happen. Why is that?

How can I avoid line break in such case?

Comment: Have you considered `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent element? That said, I'm not entirely sure what result you expected that HTML/CSS to generate, or what result you're getting that you don't want.

Comment: Demo please. It works fine. Maybe you're seeing the line wrapping around in which case, try David's suggestion.

Comment: Can you please try making the div inline-block within the style attribute? I'm suspecting you have some typo. I just copied your html and pasted and just added style attribute and it works.

Comment: X &nbsp; use like this or for only space  &nbsp;

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev You have to adjust the entire width to see the wrapping.

Comment: So, you want the `X` and the following `<div>` to behave as a single block when wrapping occurs? So a line-break can occur after the `<div>` but not after the `X`?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes. That is what I explicitly wrote. But I don't want to change the HTML structure.

Comment: That was definitely not there when I read your question the first time, my apologies for any perceived insult, hence my confusion in my first comment. Also, the fact that you "*dont want to change the HTML structure*" doesn't mean you won't have to in order to implement this.

Comment: @DavidThomas It is right that I added that part after the edit. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: using `span` instead of `<div class="inline">` solves the problem?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Using `span` and removing `display: inline-block;` seems to solve the problem, but for other reasons, I need it to have `display: inline-block;` property.

Comment: Can you add all the further information and requirements to your question? *Why* does it need to be `display: inline-block` for example?

Comment: @DavidThomas Because it has internal block structure.

Comment: Yes, *I know*; but it remains that your specific requirements (and reasons, ideally) should be in the question, rather than in the comments (which are transient and prone to deletion).

Answer (score 1):

```
    <style>
.inline{display: list-item;}

</style>

<div>
  X &nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X &nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X &nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X &nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X &nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X &nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X &nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
  X &nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div>
</div>



<div>
  <div class="inline">X &nbsp;Foo</div>
  <div class="inline">X &nbsp;Foo</div>
  <div class="inline">X &nbsp;Foo</div>
  <div class="inline">X &nbsp;Foo</div>
  <div class="inline">X &nbsp;Foo</div>
  <div class="inline">X &nbsp;Foo</div>
  <div class="inline">X &nbsp;Foo</div>
</div>
```

You can use Like this and its working for me

Answer (score -2):

Just wrap your that code with one parent div for each, it will solved your issue:-

Just replace your HMTL with following :-

```
<div>X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div></div>
<div>X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div></div>
<div>X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div></div>
<div>X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div></div>
<div>X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div></div>
<div>X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div></div>
<div>X&nbsp;<div class="inline">Foo</div></div>
```

It may help you.

Comment: No, that will not solve my issue. I want line wrapping to happen at natural width, but just avoid wrapping at certain points.

Comment: Did you actually try this?

Answer (score -2):

The HTML engine keeps the white spaces.

Take this for example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <style>
        * {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        span{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <span>Why are there spaces (margin & padding =0)</span>
    <span>between</span>
    <span>the inline elements?</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Open it in your browser and you will see that there is a gap between the inline elements.

In order to avoid it write all in a single line

Comment: No, I haven't put white spaces between `X`, `&nbsp;`, and `<div class="inline">Foo</div>`. I only put white spaces where I allow breaking. I did just as I showed in the question.

Comment: You have line break which is the same. if they are not on the same line its considered as line break. any of those is space: [ space, line break, tab, new line, \r\n and more]

Comment: Where I have line break in the code is where I allow line break in the result.

Comment: So place the opening tag on the same line of the closing tag if you don't want the line break. ex: `<div>...</div><div> [line break here if you wish which will be ignored</div>`

Answer (score -2):

Think this will hep:

```
<div>
  <div class="wrap">
    X&nbsp;<span class="inline">Foo</span>
  </div>
    <div class="wrap">
    X&nbsp;<span class="inline">Foo</span>
  </div>
    <div class="wrap">
    X&nbsp;<span class="inline">Foo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    X&nbsp;<span class="inline">Foo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    X&nbsp;<span class="inline">Foo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    X&nbsp;<span class="inline">Foo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    X&nbsp;<span class="inline">Foo</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.wrap { display: inline-block; whitespace: nowrap;}
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkuu61j1/)

the key is to keep the X foo code as a block (inline-block) so you can apply the white space rule and make the inner div a span so it becomes inline nor block.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: should be `white-space: nowrap;` with a hyphen